# Store all input[type='checkbox'] in a variable descending from multiple classnames

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that to get all the check-boxes of a specific DOM i should do  something like

```
var checks =  $(".anyParentClassName input[type='checkbox']");
```

but what if i need to save in the same variable the check-boxes coming from two different parents.Something like

```
  var checks =  $(".anyParentClassName1 input[type='checkbox']",
                  ".anyParentClassName2 input[type='checkbox']");
```

have any idea??
thanks

Comment: [`$("selector1, selector2")`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: ok it was indeed easy..agree about the downvote of the post..

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of what you did is a [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1). It is saying find the checkboxes (parent1) inside these checkboxes (parent2).

You want to just combine them into one string just like a CSS Selector rules.

```
$(".anyParentClassName1 input[type='checkbox'], .anyParentClassName2 input[type='checkbox']")
```

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses CSS selectors syntax, so just:

```
var checks =  
    $(".parent1 input[type='checkbox'], .parent2 input[type='checkbox']");
```

will get you what you need.